# Facebook scraper gives http 404, but the site is reachable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook scraper keeps returning HTTP code 404 for every article on www.krausmagazin.cz (for example https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.krausmagazin.cz%2Fvanoce-jsou-svatky-klidu-miru-a-uklidu%2F). The site is crawled without any problems by all other services (like Google).

We have the same site on different domain (used during development, but the server and files are the same) and it seems to get scraped just fine (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fkrausmagazin.cz.beta.nen.cz%2Fvanoce-jsou-svatky-klidu-miru-a-uklidu%2F).

Response headers and content are basically the same on both adresses, so if anyone has any idea what could be the problem here, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook can't scrape meta data after I've moved Wordpress to new server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220600/facebook-cant-scrape-meta-data-after-ive-moved-wordpress-to-new-server)